# iOS: Strange XCode compilation error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm building a app with Bump API and Facebook SDK.
And at some point suddenly an error appeared which hasn't been there before.
The strange thing is, that it first was in an Facebook SDK header file and now it's in Bumper.h.

[image: XCode Error]

I'm pretty sure that the error is not where XCode says it is. But i can't find anything. This is pretty frustrating and it once again confirms that XCode can be a REAL pain.

Somebody of you have any ideas what could be wrong? I'm developing with iOS 5. Thx

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild? You should also take a look at your .pch file to see if everything is ok in there (might be a included file from .pch, or a method declaration or `#define`)

Comment: This is my .pch file seems fine i guess.
`#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Travel up the include chain. The actual error will be in something that includes Bumper.h or an include in the file that includes Bumper.h (and so on till you get to the missing @end , } or ; )

When a compile is done all the includes are glued together into one file which is why you are seeing the consequences of the syntax error in the wrong place.

Comment: Thx. I'll check that. I'll be back ;)

Comment: Now hold on to your hats.
In my main.m file the first line (where comments are generated): -//

See this '-'? That was causing the problem. So actually the include chain was wandering aaaall the way from the top thing (main.m) and showed me the error at some external sdk-file. A little but unfair, but anyway. THANK YOU VERY MUCH, YOU GUYS AND STACKOVERFLOW IS AWESOME